# Get Json Value from text

Tags: java, api, groovy, automation

I have a REST response, which contains text and JSON value. I need to get uniqueId from JSON value, what will be the best way?

My JSON is very big, but looks like this:

paymentResponse = Published your custom Transaction json to topic env_txn_endtoend_01 Final json: {"txnId":null, "envelope":{"uniqueId":234234_2344432_23442","rootID":"34534554534" etc...}}

How can I get this uniqueId value = 234234_2344432_23442?

Answer (score 0):

There are many libraries to help with Json Serialization and Deserialization. [Jackson Object Mapper](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) is one of the most popular ones.

The code would be something like this.  To begin with you would need Java Pojo which represents your json Object e.g. let's consider this example from [this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial), where you can create a Car Java Object from a Car json string.

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
String json = "{ \"color\" : \"Black\", \"type\" : \"BMW\" }";
Car car = objectMapper.readValue(json, Car.class);  // you should have a Car Class(Pojo) with color, and type attributes
```

Comment: FYI... We provide classes like `JsonSlurper` which simplify parsing data from JSON without necessarily having to map to a custom type like the `Car` class mentioned above.  There are times when object mapping is helpful of course but it is generally overkill if the goal is just to retrieve values from the JSON.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown that is interesting (I always hate the boilerplate needed for just extraction purposes).  Is there a significant performance/memory gain?

Comment: "Is there a significant performance/memory gain?" - It depends on a number of factors.  One (not the only one) is the volume of input which the question characterizes as "very big".  As an example, if the JSON contains hundreds or thousands of Cars and you just need a list of thousands of VIN numbers, there is no good reason to create hundreds or thousands of Car objects on the heap just so I can invoke `getVin()` on each of them.

Comment: The maps required to create the Cars have to be created regardless of whether or not Car objects are being created, so the Car creation is all unused overhead, unless there is some other reasons(s) to want the Car instances.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown What you said makes complete sense. But additionally I was curious to know how these 2 lines "def json = slurper.parseText(jsonString); def envelope = json.envelope" hold up in terms of performance against Jackson parsing.

Comment: "I was curious to know how [...] hold up in terms of performance against Jackson parsing" - In general the Jackson parsing is going to have to do all the stuff that would happen without the object mapping so the object mapping is additional overhead.  How much additional overhead depends on a number of factors.

Answer (score 0):

> Final json: {"txnId":null,
> "envelope":{"uniqueId":234234_2344432_23442","rootID":"34534554534"
> etc...}}
>
> How can i get this uniqueId value = 234234_2344432_23442

You could do something like this:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

...

String jsonString = '{"txnId":null, "envelope":{"uniqueId":"234234_2344432_23442","rootID":"34534554534"}}'
def slurper = new JsonSlurper()
def json = slurper.parseText(jsonString)

def envelope = json.envelope

String rootId = envelope.rootID
assert rootId == '34534554534'

String uniqueId = envelope.uniqueId
assert uniqueId == '234234_2344432_23442'
```